How to export OpenTelemetry traces from WinForms app?
I am trying to use OpenTelemetry in .Net 8 WinForms app to Prometheus / Grafana in docker.
The basic code comes from Getting Started with Prometheus and Grafana
The problem is, that metrics are not pushed to Prometheus.
And pulling can't be used because there are multiple instances of app running on windows / can be running on different accounts and port will be busy.
Theoretically, this should work, but it doesn't
.AddOtlpExporter(options =>
{
    options.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:4317");
})

Program.cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{

    var resourceBuilder = ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
        .AddService("WinFormsOpenTelemetryMetrics");

    // Configure Tracing
    Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
        .SetResourceBuilder(resourceBuilder)
        .AddSource("WinFormsOpenTelemetryActivitySource")
        .AddConsoleExporter()
        .AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
        {
            otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:9090/api/v1/otlp/v1/traces");
            otlpOptions.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
            otlpOptions.ExportProcessorType = ExportProcessorType.Batch;
        })
        .Build();

    // Configure Metrics
    Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
        .SetResourceBuilder(resourceBuilder)
        .AddMeter("WinFormsOpenTelemetryMeter")
        .AddProcessInstrumentation()
        .AddRuntimeInstrumentation()
        .AddConsoleExporter()
        .AddOtlpExporter((exporterOptions, metricReaderOptions) =>
        {
            exporterOptions.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:9090/api/v1/otlp/v1/metrics");
            exporterOptions.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
            metricReaderOptions.PeriodicExportingMetricReaderOptions.ExportIntervalMilliseconds = 1000;
        })
        .Build();

    ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

    var container = Configure();
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        Application.Run(scope.Resolve<Form1>());
    }
}

I can see MyFruitCounter in Grafana.
private static readonly Meter MyMeter = new("WinFormsOpenTelemetryMeter", "1.0");
private static readonly Counter<long> MyFruitCounter = MyMeter.CreateCounter<long>("MyFruitCounter");

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyFruitCounter.Add(DateTime.Now.Second, new("name", "lemon"), new("color", "yellow"));
}

But there are no traces from
static readonly ActivitySource _sSource = new ActivitySource("WinFormsOpenTelemetryActivitySource");

private async void timerTracing_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Activity a = _sSource.StartActivity("SomeWork"))
    {
        await StepOne();
        await StepTwo();
    }
}

static async Task DoSomeWork()
{
    using (Activity a = _sSource.StartActivity("SomeWork"))
    {
        await StepOne();
        await StepTwo();
    }
}

Question:
Is it possible to to at all? Where to look for the answer?
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--enable-feature=otlp-write-receiver'
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    networks:
      - monitoring
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
    networks:
      - monitoring
  otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest
    container_name: otel-collector
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yml"]
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector-config.yml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yml
    ports:
        - "1888:1888" # pprof extension
        - "8888:8888" # Prometheus metrics exposed by the Collector
        - "8889:8889" # Prometheus exporter metrics
        - "13133:13133" # health_check extension
        - "4317:4317" # OTLP gRPC receiver
        - "4318:4318" # OTLP http receiver
        - "55679:55679" # zpages extension
    networks:
      - monitoring
volumes:
  grafana-storage:
networks:
  monitoring:


The question's title says "how to export traces", but the description says "The problem is, that metrics are not pushed to Prometheus". Further on, it says "I can see MyFruitCounter in Grafana" - does this mean that metrics are available in Grafana? And later "But there are no traces". So is it a problem with metrics or with traces? And if it's about traces, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think Grafana and Prometheus only accept metrics, and not traces or logs. Also, if OTel Collector is involved, please also post the collector's configuration.
